# To submit an issue include the stack trace

Tags: shopify

i use the command -> shopify theme serve then appears this error:

X An unexpected error occured.
To submit an issue include the stack trace.

? Send an anonymized error report to Shopify? (You chose: No, don't send)
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/shopify_cli/theme/file.rb:137:in `[]=': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError) from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/shopify_cli/theme/file.rb:137:in` visit_value'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/shopify_cli/theme/file.rb:130:in `block in visit_hash' from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/shopify_cli/theme/file.rb:129:in` each'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/shopify_cli/theme/file.rb:129:in `visit_hash' from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/shopify_cli/theme/file.rb:124:in` visit_document'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/shopify_cli/theme/file.rb:113:in `normalize_json' from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/shopify_cli/theme/file.rb:81:in` checksum'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/shopify_cli/theme/syncer/checksums.rb:20:in `file_has_changed?'         from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/shopify_cli/theme/syncer/json_update_handler.rb:19:in` block in enqueue_json_updates'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/shopify_cli/theme/syncer/json_update_handler.rb:19:in `select' from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/shopify_cli/theme/syncer/json_update_handler.rb:19:in` enqueue_json_updates'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/shopify_cli/theme/syncer.rb:173:in `upload_theme!' from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/project_types/theme/ui/sync_progress_bar.rb:11:in` public_send'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/project_types/theme/ui/sync_progress_bar.rb:11:in `block in progress'   from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/vendor/deps/cli-ui/lib/cli/ui/progress.rb:34:in` progress'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/project_types/theme/ui/sync_progress_bar.rb:10:in `progress' from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/project_types/theme/commands/serve.rb:31:in` block in call'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/shopify_cli/theme/dev_server.rb:56:in `block in start' from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/vendor/deps/cli-ui/lib/cli/ui/frame.rb:103:in` open'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/shopify_cli/theme/dev_server.rb:52:in `start' from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/project_types/theme/commands/serve.rb:30:in` call'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/shopify_cli/command/sub_command.rb:16:in `call' from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/shopify_cli/command.rb:27:in` call'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/shopify_cli/core/executor.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in call' from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:37:in` block (2 levels) in with_logging'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/vendor/deps/cli-ui/lib/cli/ui/stdout_router.rb:169:in `with_id' from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:36:in` block in with_logging'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/vendor/deps/cli-ui/lib/cli/ui.rb:176:in `log_output_to' from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:35:in` with_logging'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/shopify_cli/core/executor.rb:16:in `block in call' from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:45:in` block (2 levels) in with_traps'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:51:in `twrap' from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:44:in` block in with_traps'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:51:in `twrap' from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:43:in` with_traps'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/shopify_cli/core/executor.rb:15:in `call' from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/shopify_cli/core/entry_point.rb:24:in` block in call'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/shopify_cli/core/monorail.rb:26:in `log' from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/lib/shopify_cli/core/entry_point.rb:23:in` call'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/bin/shopify:50:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>' from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/error_handler.rb:75:in` handle_abort'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/error_handler.rb:21:in `call' from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/bin/shopify:49:in` block in <top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.18.1/bin/shopify:59:in `<top (required)>' from C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/shopify:32:in` load'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/shopify:32:in `'

Answer (score 0):

Hey before running the command make sure you check these:

- You are in the theme root folder.
- You are logged in using `shopify login` and you have the right to edit themes.
- You are connected to your internet.

If all of these are checked you might wanna reduce the Shopify version to a lower version like 2.5.0, or submit a bug in Shopify CLI in Github here: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-cli/issues

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today.

In my case, I had an article.json template file with a bad JSON structure. After providing a value for the block and then defining type, label, and limit, I was able to sync my theme again.

**Wrong structure**

```
"blocks": {
    "title": {
      "type": "article_title",
      "label": "Title",
      "limit": 1
    },
    "type": "article_image",
    "label": "Image",
    "limit": 1
  },
```

**Correct structure**

```
"blocks": {
    "title": {
      "type": "article_title",
      "label": "Title",
      "limit": 1
    },
    "image": {
      "type": "article_image",
      "label": "Image",
      "limit": 1
    }
  },
```